# FM/DAB radio which allows to connect bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I am looking for a device which offers

- FM radio or DAB radio
- No wifi connection required
- Can be plugged into a power socket (no batteries)
- Allows to connect a Bluetooth headset to listen to the music.

I have been looking online, and I found this device:
https://www.pure.com/nl/dab-radio/products/move-t4/black

But if possible, I would like to have something a little cheaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the device I'm looking for does not exist.
I created it by combining a DAB+ radio with a Bluetooth transmitter.

DAB+ radio: https://www.vr-radio.de/DAB-Digitalradio-im-Holzgehaeuse-FM-2-Weckze-ZX-1771-919.shtml
Bluetooth transmitter: https://www.ugreen.com.cn/products/bluetooth-4-2-audio-transmitter